# Bind two datasources into one grid

Tags: asp.net

I have two input controls through which I need to browse and upload the documents.

Below is my ascx

I need to have both teh files uploaded in the gridview.

Below is the code on how I am trying to achieve this.I am creating a datatable for the first upload and then a second datatable for the second upload, and then merging the twodatables into a new combined one and assigning that as the datasource for the gridview.

```
  namespace Sharepoint.WebParts.Upload_WebPart
  {
  public partial class Upload_WebPartUserControl : UserControl
   {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnUpload.Click += new EventHandler(btnUploadUploadClick);
        this.uploadsupport.Click+=new EventHandler(uploadsupport_Click);
        this.btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
        this.dgdUpload.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(dgdUpload_RowDeleting);
    }

    protected void btnUploadUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(inputFile.PostedFile.FileName);
            string x = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            if (fileName != "")
                {
                    if (x == ".zip")
                    {
                        string _fileTime = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString();
                    string _fileorgPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(inputFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string _newfilePath = _fileTime + "~" + fileName;
                    length = (inputFile.PostedFile.InputStream.Length) / 1024;
                    string tempFolder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
                    string _filepath = tempFolder + _newfilePath;
                    inputFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(_filepath);
                    AddRow(fileName, _filepath, length);
                    lblMessage.Text = "Successfully Added in List";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Please upload a zip file";
                    return;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Select a File";
                return;
            }

    }
   private void AddMoreColumns()
    {
         dt = new DataTable("DT");
         dc = new DataColumn("FileName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         dc = new DataColumn("FilePath", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         dc = new DataColumn("FileSize", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         dc = new DataColumn("KB", Type.GetType("System.String"));
         dt.Columns.Add(dc);
         Page.Session["DT"] = dt; 

    }

    private void AddRow(string file, string path, double length)
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Page.Session["DT"];

        if (dt == null)
        {
            AddMoreColumns();
        }
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["FileName"] = file;
        dr["FilePath"] = path;           
        dr["FileSize"] = Convert.ToString(length);
        dr["KB"] = "KB";          
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Page.Session["DT"] = dt;

    }

    Similary i add rows to the datatable dt1.

    protected void bindgridview()
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Page.Session["DT"];
        dt1 = (DataTable)Page.Session["DT1"];

        joineddt = (DataTable)Page.Session["Files"];
        if (joineddt == null)
        {
            joineddt = dt.Copy();
            joineddt.Merge(dt1);
        }

        this.dgdUpload.DataSource = joineddt;
        this.dgdUpload.DataBind();
        Page.Session["Files"] = joineddt;

    }}
```

}

Please help me to correct this , also is there a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: There's a lot of code to comb through here, so let's start with some initial debugging... At the heart of the error is that the grid binding assumes the existence of the column `SupportName`.  (It's your second `HyperLinkField` element.)  Does the table `joineddt` have such a column at runtime?

Comment: I got passed that error. Now , I am getting 2 rows wherein i just should get one row with both the attachments...can you put in some thought please

Comment: Just requires more debugging on your part.  Where are those rows coming from?  When do they each get added to the table?  Find where they're being added and therein will be the logic that needs to change.  Maybe one is added and then later the second is added?  If that's the case, you probably want the second to be an update instead of an insert.  Maybe they're both added at the same time?  Then you may need to edit where they're coming from or how they're added, or manually merge them and delete the second one after the fact.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't databind to more than one data source at the same time.  If the datatable `joineddt` does not have `SupportName` in it then your code would not work.

Rather than trying to try an finagle 2 data sources into one GridView, you should create one data source that has all the data you expect to display in a row of the GridView in one row of the data source.